# Is White Widow the daughter of Max from the first Mission: Impossible movie?

Tags: character, mission-impossible, mission-impossible-fallout

In *Mission: Impossible - Fallout* we meet the character of White Widow (Vanessa Kirby), an arms dealer, on some party in Paris. In her speech she commemorates her mother, naming her "Max".

In the first *Mission: Impossible* movie in the series, the 1996 Brian de Palma one, Max is the name (or an alias) of Vanessa Redgrave's character, also an arms dealer, who is the movie's antagonist.

Could it be the same Max? Is *Fallout*'s White Widow the daughter of Vanessa Redgrave's character? Is there some confirmed information on the subject?

Comment: Turns out I'm old, when I read "first Mission: Impossible" and assumed that you meant the [first Mission: Impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission:_Impossible).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Yes**,  Vanessa Kirby confirmed herself:

> Talking to Digital Spy, The Crown's Vanessa Kirby has revealed that her enigmatic character, the White Widow, is the daughter of arms dealer Max, played by Vanessa Redgrave, in the first movie. - [digitalspy](http://www.digitalspy.com/movies/mission-impossible/news/a861554/mission-impossible-6-cast-vanessa-kirby-character-vanessa-redgrave/)